# Wet bar Sink Drain water backs into sink

Tags: plumbing, sink, pump

I recently installed the drain and sink pump. I am having a problem with water going back to the sink after 4-8 hours (1/4 inch of water). This is enough to keep the sink pump cycling. Attached is a diagram with the location of the sink pump, distances, check valve, and ball valve. My best bet is that the check valve is not in the proper place but I had it closer to the sink pump horizontally and I though that putting it vertically would help but didn't do much (the check valve I have is supposed to work in horizontal applications as well but didn't seem to be the case). Please advise[image]

Comment: I'm no plumbing expert, but I would think there should be an ordinary trap between the sink and the pump.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, the manual of the sink pump is explicit that this one does not require a p trap (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-3-HP-Utility-Sink-Pump-LTS250A/301015850)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way water can flow back is for the check valve to leak. Per your drawing the valve is below the bottom of the sink. Your best solution is to replace the check valve. You could put one on the sink pump outlet but that may cause problems in the future.

Comment: The check valve is brand new and seemed fine. It may just be a bad quality one. I initially had it installed close to the sink pump horizontally right where the long pipe begins (the horizontal line with a slope) the leak was a bit worse in that particular case (about 1/2 inch of water in the sink bowl). The check valve I'm using has a spring and is supposed to work if installed either horizontal or vertical.

Comment: Try removing it and be sure it is clean and has no contamination in it. I have been assuming you have a decent flow rate when the pump runs.

Comment: Flow rate is fine, the only problem I have is water backing into the sink. Do you think lowering the sink could help?

Comment: Lowering the sink will cause it to get fuller with the back flow. To solve the problem you need to stop the backflow. A valve works great for this. An automatic valve is the best. A check valve is an automatic valve. You can put anyvalve you like in the line. You state connected to the drain, is there a vent there, if not there should be.

Comment: I replaced the check valve as you suggested initially and that solved the problem. Even thought the other check valve was new, it was leaky. And yes, there is a vent on the drain line. Thanks for the advise.